# How to add new operator in C# using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to implement a DSL like feature in C#. It may look something similar to LINQ queries. I am wondering if it is possible to implement new unary or binary operators using Roslyn.

I have been googling last few days without much success. It would be great if someone could point me to some samples or Roslyn documentations.

Comment: I think you need to look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The question definitely does NOT ask for a third-party tool recommendation. Roslyn is a key feature of the latest C# version. One can say that the OP should first check Roslyn's page though.

Comment: Roslyn is a compiler, and they're [open sourcing](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/04/microsoft-open-sources-a-big-chunk-of-net/) it. So technically you could implement as many feature as you want, as long as you have the necessary skillset.

Comment: Because Roslyn did not get that much attention before it was made open-source, there is not many sources and tutorials about it. And those you could find are mostly about writing VS extensions, diagnostics and code fixes. I'm afraid you have to figure it by yourself (and when you do, you should probably share knowledge writing a blog post or something).

Comment: I recently looked into adding a new binary operator to Roslyn and I blogged about it. See [Adding Matt operator to Roslyn - Syntax, Lexer and Parser](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2017/05/adding-matt-operator-to-roslyn-part-1.html) and [Adding Matt operator to Roslyn - Binder](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2017/05/adding-matt-operator-to-roslyn-part-2.html). Part 3 with Emitter to come when I find some time to look into it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways how you could use Roslyn to implement a new C#-based language.

1. Use the Roslyn API to parse the source code into a syntax tree, then transform the syntax tree into actual C# and compile that.

   This is ideal if your language is actually syntactically valid C# code, but the semantics are different. For example, you could implement `await` this way, if you forced `await` to look like a function call (e.g. `await(x)` would be valid, but not `await x`).

   If you want to introduce new syntax (like a new operator), it might work, since Roslyn does support parsing “broken” code. But it most likely won't work that well, because then the syntax tree might not look the way you want. Worse, the results might not be consistent (sometimes, your new syntax will be parsed one way, sometimes another).
2. Since Roslyn is now open source, you can actually modify the source code of the compiler in any way you want, including adding a new operator.

   But doing that is most likely not going to be simple. And I think the workflow is also going to be more complicated: you need to compile your own version of the compiler, not just use a library from NuGet like in option 1.